# TWRP constantly crashing and rebooting back

Tags: android, custom-rom

My phone (*Nexus 5*) is constantly rebooting to the TWRP screen where it crashes, shuts down and repeats.

**TWRP error**:

```
Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
...done
Unable to mount storage
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Full SELinux support is present.
Running Recovery Commands
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Formatting Cache using make_ext4fs...
Done processing script file
Renamed stock recovery file in /system to prevent the stock ROM from replacing TWRP.
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
```

**What I did before I *broke* it**:

1. Shut down the phone.
2. Booted the phone into the fastboot mode. (*Pow + Vol Down*)
3. On PC (*through USB cable*) I ran these commands:

   - `fastboot oem unlock` -> which asks for an agreement and deletes the whole system
   - `fastboot flash recovery Downloads/twrp.img` - I had the file renamed and it was located in the Downloads folder
4. Rebooted to the *Recovery mode* (*2x Vol Up and Pow*)

**So what am I supposed to do to successfully flash a custom recovery if not this way?**

Comment: flash correct recovery, https://twrp.me/lg/lgnexus5.html,

Comment: I did that obviously. I flashed this version: twrp-3.2.1-1-hammerhead.img

Comment: wrong site. Try superuser or android.se

Answer (score 11):

I also faced with this issue and I found solution.

Go to `bootolader` and then execute:

```
fastboot -w
```

to wipe the data from the phone (it will erase all user data and internal storage)

after that go to `recovery` by calling:

```
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: With this solution the problem for me was, that my installed Android platform tools were too old ("error: Cannot generate image for userdata"). I used the platform tools from Ubuntu which were too old. I downloaded the current version from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: This saved me on a Nexus7 Tablet! Thanks alot!

Comment: lifesaver solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: I held the volume-up button during the loop, swiped when prompted to allow modifications, then got to the TWRP main screen. I had already downloaded a purportedly-stock image from https://firmwarefile.com/blu-dash-x2-d110l, so I then did:

```
adb push ../Blu_D110L_MT6580_V22_GENERIC/Firmware/recovery.img /tmp/
```

And from TWRP, Install, Flash image, located /tmp/recovery.img, swiped. Rebooted,
and had a brand-new phone again.